# How is String's + operator implmemented?

Tags: java

What happens when executing

```
String s = "str" + 2;
```

Is there a method of `String` class that correspond exactly to the `+` operator?

Comment: Create a small testcase and use javap to disassemble it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1) (emphasis mine):

> If only **one** operand expression is of **type String**, then string **conversion** (§5.1.11) is performed **on the other operand** to produce a string at run time.
>   The result of string concatenation is a reference to a String object that is the concatenation of the two operand strings.

Comment: I don't think this fully answers the question. The duplicate does a much better job...